# Using ESLint on server files with CRA

Tags: create-react-app, eslintrc, prettier-eslint

In VS Code - When running CRA and setting up a simple file structure with `backend` and `frontend` directories, the frontend (React) files are linted automatically by ESLint, but there is no syntax highlighting in the `backend` server files.

We have tried multiple .eslintrc.js files in various places in the project (in the root etc) but the syntax highlighting (errors, warnings) for the files in `backend` doesn't occur.

In a non-react project this is working fine in VS Code with a `.eslintrc.js` file in the root.

IS CRA config overriding any other?

We have tried eg:

```
Adding the following snippet to settings.json in VS code

"eslint.validate": [
  "javascript",
  "javascriptreact",
  "typescript",
  "typescriptreact"
],
```

But this doesn't make any difference.